# ansible how can i add condition to get_url modul to not include or include the owner and group properties from include_role

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

i have include_role im using from playbook which working file, i like to be able to use it from 
different playbooks, but not all playbooks needs all of the get_url properties to be executed.
for example :

```
- name: Download
  include_role:
    name: utilities
    tasks_from: download
  vars:
    dest: "{{ ansible_env.APP }}/"
    url: "{{ url }}"
```

and this role :

```
---
- name: Download_role
  get_url:
    url_username: "{{ packages_user }}"
    url_password: "{{ packages_pass }}"
    dest: "{{ dest }}"
    url: "{{ url }}"
    owner: "{{ ansible_user|default('ec2-user') }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_user|default('ec2-user') }}"
```

now the default call to this role it will set default owner and group properties on the file 
but what if i don't like it to invoke/use the owner and group properties when i call the same  include_role from a different playbook

can i add if / else in the Download_role surrounding the owner and group? in the role
or any other ansible magic method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application of the *`default`* filter does not make sense here

```
    owner: "{{ ansible_user|default('ec2-user') }}"
```

The variable [ansible_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables) is always defined.

---

To answer your question:

Q: *"Can I add if/else in the 'Download_role' surrounding the owner and group? In the role or any other Ansible magic method?"*

A: There is both *if/else* and magic method available. It's  possible to use if / else

```
    owner: "{{ 'userA'  if my_condition else 'userB' }}"
```

, or the [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter

```
    owner: "{{ my_condition|ternary('userA', 'userB') }}"
```

This limits the selection to two options only. Replace *`my_condition`* with Boolean variable or with a logical expression.

---

The best practice is to define a role's defaults in [defaults/main.yml](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-default-variables). For example, the role's defaults may look like

```
shell> cat roles/utilities/defaults/main.yml
my_user: user_A
```

Then the value of the parameter *`owner`* in the role *`utilities`* is by default *`user_A`*

```
    owner: "{{ my_user }}"
```

Here comes the magic. It's possible to select a file with the default values by
[defaults_from](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#parameter-defaults_from) when a role is included by *`include_role`*. For example, let's create additional default files

```
shell> cat roles/utilities/defaults/opt_B.yml
my_user: user_B

shell> cat roles/utilities/defaults/opt_C.yml
my_user: user_C
```

Then, for example, let's use the defaults from the file *`opt_B.yml`* in the included role

```
- name: Download
  include_role:
    name: utilities
    tasks_from: download
    defaults_from: opt_B.yml
```

See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Comment: Thank for the detailed answer but i like to not set the default at all i want not to use owner property at all in some conditions

Comment: i mean (your i didn't understand right ..) in all of your example i have to set default value 
which will be executed in the end , this is i want to avoid